# Investment or saving options Northern Europe

Tags: savings, interest

I am interested in basic financial advice for my current situation. I am mid twenties, living in Northern Europe and have gathered some savings over the years. Currently living in a rented apartment, and not planning to move for at least 2-3 years. I have a stable income, from which I can pay my monthly dues and still save at least 500€ each month. However, I feel that I am currently waisting that money in the bank.

My money is currently split over three banks
- almost €40k in one bank, on which I currently receive 0.3% interest
- €15k in a second bank, with an interest rate below 0.1%
- around $10k in a US bank following a work period there, which I intend to move to Europe as soon as possible (should I wait for a suitable moment in currency rate?)

I believe it would be smart to talk with an investment advisor at my local branch, but was hoping to get additional advice from here. I am looking for long-term stable investments / banking options, not here for a high-risk big-wins game. Any comments or links to relevant information would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I presume the same sorts of investment opportunities exist in Europe as do in the US. If so, the many answers here on getting started investing should be good starting points for your own research.  First step is an emergency fund, second is to pay off high-intrrest-rate loans and credit card balances, then you need to consider your time scale before you need the money and how risk-tolerant you are and thus pick an investment strategy. Remember that mutual fund fees subtract directly from returns, which is why low-fee index funds are a win. The advisor should explain all this  in more detail.

Comment: I think this question may be too general for this platform. You're basically asking "I have some money saved up, how can I generate the best returns"? It's a fair enough question, but this forum works best when directed towards specific questions.